# Using java provided parameters into xpath function while applying xslt transformation

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm working at a java application that performs some xslt transformation.
I would like to match nodes into the xslt document, using a parameter provided by java.
Which is the right way to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="//m:properties/*[contains($pattern,name())]">
```

because when I launch my application, it claims it's not able to compile the stylesheet, since pattern is not defined but I'm setting it using the setParameter method and I was able to use another parameter defined in the same way but in a different context.
Thanks in advance
Fil

Comment: Sorry, between ... and ... there was the code excerpt:
<xsl:template match="//m:properties/*[contains($pattern,name())]">

Comment: What version of XSLT (1.0 or 2.0)?  Variable references are not allowed in match expressions in 1.0.

Comment: I'm afraid 1.0, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an

```
<xsl:param name="pattern" />
```

in your stylesheet to declare the parameter, the `setParameter` call is not sufficient on its own.  However there is a further problem that, according to the XSLT 1.0 spec, match expressions are not allowed to contain variable/parameter references like `$pattern`.  Some processors do permit them anyway (including at least some versions of Xalan), but if it doesn't work then you need to change the matching logic, e.g. by defining the template to match `//m:properties/*` but then only calling `apply-templates` for those elements that match your pattern.

Comment: Thaks Ian, declaring the parameter as you suggested, it worked :)

Comment: @filmac OK, but be careful if you're relying on the fact that the default processor violates the spec - `TransformerFactory` is pluggable, and if someone runs your app with a different (stricter) processor on the classpath it may fail to compile the stylesheet...